# Order by the values based on search values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 3 columns

```
id | name                   | description
------------------------------------------
 1 | Service marketing      |   Description for the marketing
 2 | Marketing              |   Service marketing
 3 | Great customer Service |   Helpful  shows your customers that you really do care about them.
```

I want to search the values based on 'Service' from both the column name,description and also i need to order the values in asc order by name and description.I am expecting the result set as below.

```
id | name                   | description
------------------------------------------
 1 | Service marketing      |   Description for the marketing
 3 | Great customer Service |   Helpful  shows your customers that you really do care about them.
 2 | Marketing              |   Service marketing
```

I have tried the below queries but not works

```
SELECT * FROM search  where `name` LIKE '%service%'
OR `description` LIKE '%service%'
ORDER BY name,description;
```

Result for above query

```
id | name                   | description
------------------------------------------
3  |Great customer Service  |   Helpful  shows your customers that you really do c...
2  |Marketing               |   Service marketing
1  |Service marketing       |   Description for the marketing
```

Help me on this. Thanks

Comment: You want sort the result by the position of word service inside the two columns?

Comment: What is the sort criteria ? From your example seems that you need to sort first by 'description' and then by 'name' but I'm not sure if this is what you want

Comment: I am searching with the value based on service using LIKE. In name column ID 1,3 holds the value service , so first i need to order by name after the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want ordered by position of 'Service' in the columns you should use this

```
select position('Service' IN name) as p1, name, position('Service' IN  description) as p2, description 
from my table 
where  position('Service' IN name) != 0 
and position('Service' IN  description) != 0
order by p1 desc, p2 desc;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' name) as p1, name, position('Service' , description) as p2, description from se' at line 1

Comment: Thanks.I will check.

Comment: If p1 and p2 is zero. I donot want to get this value.How can i add the condition in that query?

Comment: I have update  the answer with the where condition for p1 and p2  = 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
SELECT S.*, 
case 
WHEN position('service', name) = 0 THEN 65535
ELSE position('service', name) 
END as p1,
case 
WHEN position('service', description) = 0 THEN 65535
ELSE position('service', description) 
END as p2
FROM search as S where 
name LIKE '%service%' OR description LIKE '%service%'
ORDER BY p1, p2
```

since you need ASC order

Comment: I am getting error like this

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' name) = 0 THEN 65535 ELSE position('service', name) END as p1, case WHEN posi' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

hey you can use following query to get your expecting result

```
select position('Service' in name) as p1, name,position('Service' in    description) as p2,description from dd order by p2,name desc
```

your expecting result

```
id | name                   | description
------------------------------------------
1 | Service marketing      |   Description for the marketing
3 | Great customer Service |   Helpful  shows your customers that you really   do care about them.
2 | Marketing              |   Service marketing
```